# Serlialize array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to serialise my array but I'm getting nothing in the log.

I want all checkboxes called color[] but not the first one.

I've tried:

```
$("input[name='color[]:not(:first)']").serialize();
```

But this logs as blank.

The following works but includes the first one, so it must be a problem with the not part.

```
 $("input[name='color[]']").serialize();
```

Comment: Look at where your single quotes are. The selector is looking for an `input` with a `name` equal to `color[]:not(:first)`, like `<input name="color[]:not(:first)" />`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your **[attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** is wrong  `$("input[name='color[]:not(:first)']")`

```
$("input[name='color[]']:not(:first)").serialize();
```

Answer (score 5):

The `selector` you are using is wrong.

Finish `]` after the `name=value` selector.

```
$("input[name='color[]']:not(:first)").serialize();
```

Here are the mistakes highlighted:

```
$("input[name='color[]:not(:first)']").serialize();
//                    ^     finish selector here
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this

```
$("input[name='color[]']:not(:first)").serialize();
```